Using Google Scripts to Forward Email based on Contacts Membership to a Group or Label
I am attempting some first time script writing to build a script that will auto-forward emails received in a one inbox (let's say mine) to another email based on the incoming sender's membership to a label in my Contact list. Seemed simple enough... but I am a first time coder, using some resources and ChatGPT.
I've done the following:

Enabled People API and connected the right project along with OAuths.
Json scripted the following:
--"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"
--"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
I have my label resource ID.

My problem is that that code executes but does not pull from the people API or simply won't forward the emails.
I'm getting this error: "Error during script execution: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to people.people.connections.list failed with error: Invalid personFields mask path: "group_membership". Valid paths are documented at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get."
Thanks!!
I'm using various versions of this code (I cut out the logging code). Feel free to point out the stupid mistakes... very much still learning this (like 2 days in).
`function forwardAndArchiveEmails() {
  var forwardingAddress = "logan@travelwealth.com";
  var groupId = "6d642cc6887790e9";

  // Fetch all contacts with their email addresses and memberships
  var response = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', {
    personFields: 'emailAddresses,memberships',
    pageSize: 1000
  });

  var emailAddresses = [];
  if (response && response.connections) {
    response.connections.forEach(function(person) {
      if (person.memberships) {
        person.memberships.forEach(function(membership) {
          if (membership.contactGroupMembership &&
              membership.contactGroupMembership.contactGroupId === groupId) {
            if (person.emailAddresses) {
              person.emailAddresses.forEach(function(emailInfo) {
                emailAddresses.push(emailInfo.value);
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread', 0, 5);
  threads.forEach(function(thread) {
    var messages = thread.getMessages();
    messages.forEach(function(message) {
      var fromAddress = parseSenderAddress(message.getFrom());
      if (emailAddresses.includes(fromAddress)) {
        message.forward(forwardingAddress);
        thread.moveToArchive();
      }
    });
  });
}

function parseSenderAddress(fromField) {
  var match = fromField.match(/<(.+)>/);
  return match ? match[1] : fromField;
}`

I'm getting this error: "Error during script execution: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to people.people.connections.list failed with error: Invalid personFields mask path: "group_membership". Valid paths are documented at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get."
Thanks!!
